# What is use of $.map function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Note: I just want to to understand what is $.map doing in following code..

I am working on openstack horizon,In one of the javascript file they are using $.map function Please see[horizon.d3linechar.js](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/horizon/static/horizon/js/horizon.d3linechart.js#L426-435)

My question is how $.map is works, what is $ before map. $.map is associated with javascript or jquery..

```
$.map(self.series, function(serie) {
        serie.color = last_point_color = self.color(serie.name);
        $.map(serie.data, function(statistic) {
          // need to parse each date
          statistic.x = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').parse(statistic.x);
          statistic.x = statistic.x.getTime() / 1000;
          last_point = statistic;
          last_point.color = serie.color;
        });
      });
```

Comment: $ is a "shortcut" for jQuery - to see HOW $.map works, look at the jQuery source code - https://github.com/jquery/jquery ... $.map is a jQuery function written in javascript - so - associated with both I guess

Comment: That is an inappropriate use of the map function, because neither callback returns a value, nor is the result of `$.map()` used. So in that code it is just acting the same as an `.each()` loop.

Comment: @JaromandaX `$` is not always the alias for jQuery (but in this case, it is jQuery). There are other libraries use `$` too. e.g. Prototype

Comment: @Neverever I just want to to understand what is $.map doing in mentioned code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the jQuery documentation. Their are many many examples. Our folk is realy trying to help you. But what is the lack of your understanding in the `$.map()` function?

`$` is only the namespace and makes at least the map function work. So forget about it.

`map( input, outputFunction )` is iterating through the `input` which has to be an real array. The `outputFunction`, usually a self executing function, is able to manipulate the content of each element of the inputed array.

**In your example:**

```
$.map(self.series, function(serie) {
```

`self.series` is the input and each element of that array will be called as `serie` in the anonymous or rather self executed function.

```
serie.color = last_point_color = self.color(serie.name);
```

Change some color stuff...

```
$.map(serie.data, function(statistic) {
```

Next call of the mapping function.

```
  // need to parse each date
  statistic.x = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').parse(statistic.x);
```

Parsing the date to a specific format like discribed in the comment.

```
  statistic.x = statistic.x.getTime() / 1000;
```

Take the `x` value parse to a time or maybe to seconds and divide through 1000.

```
  last_point = statistic;
```

Save element of `serie.data` to a temporar variable.

```
  last_point.color = serie.color;
```

Save the color of the of the serie to the element of that serie.

```
    });
  });
```

**All in all...**
... `$.map()` iterates through `self.series`, then iterates through its children and then it looks like it changes the color of every single element to the color of that series.

Comment: Thank you. I really appriciate, but at least my friend: Get familiar with the documantations. Every good programer puts lots and lots effort into his or her own documentation. Don't forget, that the most time of our work we are spending while reading and **trying** to understand the sourcecode ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$` is an alias for the `jQuery` object.

As for [**map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), it is an *api* function in `jQuery` used to convert the items in an array.

If you look at the [**source**](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.map) for map, the basic algorithm is to iterate over the passed in `elems` and obtain a converted value using the callback

```
function (elems, callback) {
    var value, i = 0,
        length = elems.length,
        ret = [];

      for (; i < length; i++) {
      //alternatively, for objects,  for (i in elems) {
            value = callback(elems[i], i);

            if (value != null) {
                ret.push(value);
            }
        }
    // Flatten any nested arrays
    return concat.apply([], ret);
}
```

Comment: @JaromandaX  I just want to to understand what is $.map doing in mentioned code

Comment: In the code shown in the question no actual mapping takes place. It's just being used as a looping mechanism. It's poor coding.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I concur. On the face, it seems that no effect is taking place. It cant be told for sure without seeing more code because it may be some sort of custom inner implementation of map? Idk...

Comment: @nnnnnn, it seems they are indirectly manipulating the array properties with ` statistic.x = ....`. But yes, this seems like poor coding practices

Comment: @AmmarCSE Omit unused index parameter declaration at `$.each(index, value)` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying it wouldn't *work* as a looping mechanism to change properties of the nested objects. Just that `$.each()` would be a much better choice if all they want is a loop.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I dont think so. They would be undefined values if they did `var someVariable = $.map` like above because the callback doesnt acutally return anything

Comment: @JaromandaX - No, `$.map()` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the one passed in. In this case it would return an empty array because when the callback returns `undefined` the item is not used.

Comment: yeah, I can never remember which Array functions return a new array and which don't